# Splitting A String Up To A Character

Tags: ruby, regex

I'd like to split the following string:

```
user = "Lisa: yes"
```

So that I can get "Lisa"

Right now I have :

```
user[/([a-zA-Z].*?):/]
```

but it returns

```
"Lisa:"
```

How can I split the string so that it will return each letter up to the colon?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

You can use this: `user.split(':').first`

```
user = "Lisa: yes" 
=> "Lisa: yes"
irb(main):006:0> user.split(':').first
=> "Lisa"
```

The split method will transform your string into an array, this array: **['Lisa',' yes']**. Then, you'll just got to parse it with the first method, to get the first item, `Lisa`. Simple and intuitive, because personally, I hate regular expressions. I also like Arup Rakshit answer ;)

Answer (score 4):

Do as below :

```
user = "Lisa: yes"
user[/([a-zA-Z].*?):/,1] # => "Lisa"
```

Documentation of [`str[regexp, capture]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) :

> If a Regexp is supplied, the matching portion of the string is returned. If a capture follows the regular expression, which may be a capture group index or name, follows the regular expression that component of the MatchData is returned instead.

Comment: Notice that Arup made `.*` 'lazy' (aka 'non-greedy', 'reluctant') by appending `?`. The greedy form would be `"Lisa: yes, Betty: no"[/([a-zA-Z].*):/,1] #=> "Lisa: yes, Betty"`, not what we want.

Answer (score 2):

A few more ways:

```
user[0...user.index(':')]
user.partition(':').first
user.each_line(':').first.chomp(':')
require 'stringio'
StringIO.new(user).gets(':').chomp(':')
StringIO.new(user).readline(':').chomp(':')
t = $/; $/ = ':'
user.each_line.first.chomp
StringIO.new(user).gets.chomp
StringIO.new(user).readline.chomp
$/ = t
user.chars.take_while {|c| c != ':'}.join
```

Comment: Haha +1 for options. (Though like @sidney's answer best)

Comment: Mark, those late to the dinner party must feast on crumbs.

Comment: @Jesse, +1 for spotting that. A +5 bonus if you hadn't read my edits. (Readers: I previously had `require 'useringio'`.)

Comment: @Jesse, I expect that you've discovered you need only click on the blue "Edited..." message.  Now go buy some candy with the 6 points I've given you. (I don't want to hear that you didn't know I could give you points.)

Answer (score 1):

In an attempt to refine your original regexp using a [positive lookahead anchor](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Anchors):

```
 user[/[a-zA-Z].*?(?=:)/]
 # => "Lisa"
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternately there are few other ways for reference:

```
# replacing anything after `:` with empty.
user.gsub(/:.*/, "")

# splitting the string around : and picking the first one.
user.split(/\s*:\s*/)[0]
```

Comment: Isn't the second the same as `split(':')[0]`?

Comment: @CarySwoveland yes. `\s*` means any optional space around the `:` sign.